# Asp.net MVC 5 Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routeconfig

I'm new in ASP.net MVC

My Route Config is here

```
    routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ItineraryRoute",
          url: "{country}/Itinerary/tours/{TourId}",
          defaults: new { controller = "TourDetails", action = "Index" }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "TourRoute",
           url: "{country}/tours",
           defaults: new { controller = "Tour", action = "Index" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In page `/Russia/tours`   I have a link here is the code line:

```
<a href="@ViewBag.Country/tours/Itinerary/@tour.Id">Day's By Detail's....</a>
```

When I click on this , page would be link to this Url : `/Russia/Russia/tours/Itinerary/1`

With Error 404 http not Found.

Do you have any idea why I have two Russia and how to fix it to link in 'TourDetailsController' with 'TourId'?

Comment: Perpend a `/`. But your should always use `@Url.Action()` or `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate the correct url.

Comment: Is it possible for you to answer this question and also tell me how exactly to use `@Html.ActionLink()` in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know how to thank you . thanks .

Comment: Always try your link in a browser directly (regardless of how it is generated).  If you get a 404, it's a route issue.  In this case, your route is "Itinerary/tours/" but your link is "tours/Itinerary", so won't hit your route and will give you a 404.   If you'd used `@Html.ActionLink` or `@Html.RouteLink` (or even `@Url.Action`) then this would not have happened.  I'll leave details to Stephen's answer.

Comment: Your current path+page is 'Russia/tours' you've requested 'Russia/xxx' so it removes the current page from the path to give you 'Russia' and then appends your new path to give 'Russia/Russia/xxx'

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks . Now I Understand why it happens .I dont know how to thank you. By your recommends it's better to use action link always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need perpend a `/` (forward slash) to the `href` value - i.e. so that its `href="/Russia/tours/Itinerary/1"`, but you should always use the `UrlHelper` or `HtmlHelper` methods to generate you links

Using `Url.Action()`

```cs
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "TourDetails", new { country = ViewBag.Country, tourID = tour.Id })">Day's By Detail's....</a>
```

Using `Url.RouteUrl()`

```cs
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ItineraryRoute", new { country = ViewBag.Country, tourID = tour.Id })">Day's By Detail's....</a>
```

Using `Html.Action()`

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Day's By Detail's....", "Index", "TourDetails", new { country = ViewBag.Country, tourID = tour.Id }, null)
```

Using `Html.RouteLink()`

```cs
@Html.RouteLink("Day's By Detail's....", "ItineraryRoute", new { country = ViewBag.Country, tourID = tour.Id })
```

Comment: Yes It works and really really thank you for your help and knowledge.

Comment: Just a note regarding paths with "/xxx" - the root of your website may not always be at the root of the webserver (esp if you are using IIS applications).  That's why MVC Razor views use "~/images..." etc.  If you hardcode a path to "/xxx" and your site gets moved/deployed to "/mysite", it should then be "/mysite/xxx" and the hardcoded path will stop working.   The helpers (as detailed here) handle this for you.  Always use the helpers.